# How to extract data from a column with list of dict and backslash

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

[image]
Here is the first element of a dataframe

How can I for exemple get the number of different dict or item_id value for each dict ?

The problem is that is not a list of dict. If I try to get each element of this list, the output is just all element one by one not the 3 differents list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to convert your string as list with `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast

australian_user_reviews['reviews'] = australian_user_reviews['reviews'].map(ast.literal_eval)
```

Now you can use `str.len()` to get the length of each list:

```
australian_user_reviews['count'] = australian_user_reviews['reviews'].str.len()
```